# rsync save and restore user-id/group-id

Tags: linux, backup, permissions, rsync, restore

I'm trying to understand how to save and restore user/group while performing a backup using `rsync`.
It might be that I got it all wrong, but I was running the following command:

```
 rsync -axqHAXWESR --fake-super --no-R --rsync-path="rsync --fake-super" /path/to/src/ <user>@<ip>:/path/to/dst/
```

I then went to <ip> and listed files under /path/to/dst/. they were, unsurprisingly, belong to <user>. I then ran the following:

```
 getfattr -dm '' -- /path/to/dst/*
```

I'm not sure what all parts of the output means, but the end of it seemed like the correct user-id/group-id is saved. here is one example output:

```
# file: /path/to/dst/some_file
user.rsync.%stat="100755 0,0 1000:100"
```

(and indeed, originally some_file was owned to user-id 1000 and group-id 100).

I then restored the content from <ip> to my machine (into a different directory):

```
 rsync -axqHAXWESR --fake-super --no-R --rsync-path="rsync --fake-super <user>@<ip>:/path/to/dst/ /path/to/import/
```

files under /path/to/import had (unsurprisingly) the user-id/group-id of `whoami` (which didn't originally owned some of the files). using `getfattr` to files under /path/to/import/ showed that original user-id/group-id still saved inside the XATTR.

now, I'm trying to figure out how to apply those original user-id/group-id on the imported files, but can't seem to find how to do it.
I already tried to dump the XATTR into a file, using `getfattr -Rd` for the files, and then restore them using `setattr --restore`. But it didn't seemed to be working. user-id/group-id remained as those of `whoami`.

will much appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes are rsync-specific; it is `--fake-super` that "restores" them.

But when restoring from such a backup, the rsync receiver does *not* need `--fake-super`, only the sender does. (On the sender side this option means "read rsync.%stat instead of looking at real stat", on the receiver side it means "write rsync.%stat instead of doing real chown/chmod".)

The receiver *does*, however, need to be run with root privileges as normal users cannot `chown` files.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.
I'm not sure I fully understand your answer, but I tried what I thought it means, and it indeed worked.
this is what I tried:
`sudo rsync -axqHAXWESR --no-R --rsync-path="rsync --fake-super" <user>@<ip>:/path/to/dst/ /path/to/import/`

many many thanks for the help :)